# Spring Web Flow Error MEssages

Tags: spring-webflow

I have a java web application running on Spring Web FLow,Spring Faces. I would like to ask as to how to properly manage error messages display. Should I do the usual storing of error messages on the session? Or is there a better handling by Spring regarding the matter.

Comment: have you read what the spring docs say on the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flashScope is intended for just this type of "display a once-off message to the user" usage. You can use it in combination with a resource bundle and the  or  tags to retrieve the localized error string from a key stored in the flashScope.

Spring Web Flow offers a level of automation for error messages if you make use of the [validation framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch04s10.html) so you may not even need to do the above manually. However not knowing your exact use case, it's hard to recommend a specific approach.